# listview with hovering row

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with data of 50 rows but 30th row is important row in the entire list and it should hover on top all the time and during scrolling it should get attached to the 30th row seamlessly and after pass by should still hover.This should only be done to one row.

What should be my approach or how should I even begin ?I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As grennis has mentioned, I would recommend starting with StickListHeaders. Though I would also suggest you consider the situation where your list is displaying items sat 25 to 29 (the 30th row should be visible at the top), then the user scrolls down to display the 30th row. How would your UI behave? Should the top 30th row immediately disappear and reappear at the bottom? Would there be some kind of animation between the two? The problem is you have two 30th rows being displayed, one stuck to the top and another appearing from the bottom. Good luck!

Comment: I never thought of that ,is any library similar? Can you suggest something on those lines,it may not be the same.

Comment: I cant think of any other library, but is it possible to get the 30th item to be at the top of the list, but have a clear label indicating that it is indeed the 30th item? Something like having an item number at the front of each item? This would allow you to have consistent UI behavior and always have the item displayed at the top.

Comment: Or another suggestion could be to modify the StickListHeader behavior to 'stick' the item to the top or bottom of the view depending on whether it's below or above the view position?

Comment: that sounds good.Thanks for that will try that also is there any library which has sticky header and not sections?

Comment: The headers ARE the sections. What you'll be doing is making the 30th item a header, but using the same layout as your normal items. All the best!

Comment: How do I stop section header A,B,C ... from being replaced?I would thank you for your insight.

Comment: By having only a single section header (the 30th item). However you would have to modify the StickyListHeaderView to display the header at the bottom if the index of the item you want to display is below your current view.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a new question regarding how to modify the sticky list header library for your needs, but I recommend spending a bit of time understanding what you need to do and actually giving it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this or at least use it to get you started on the right direction [StickyListHeaders on github](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)

Comment: how to make a row with data lets say 30th row contains no. 30 float nothing else not sections

Comment: Thats an entire project, you cant expect someone on SO to just post an answer with the whole thing written for you

Comment: Sorry Sir but I was looking for something on those lines.Hope to find something ,currently trying to implement sticky listview .Thanks again for your reply.But I simply addressed my concern.

Comment: Thank you Sir for extra confidence and luck.Thanks .